# Stunnel won't work with SSLv3 from some hosts

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, stunnel

**WARNING:** [SSLv3 is obsolete](https://www.openssl.org/~bodo/ssl-poodle.pdf). Consider [disabling it altogether](https://serverfault.com/questions/637312/protecting-against-poodle-ssl-on-stunnel).

I'm trying to set up Stunnel to server as SSL cache. Everything was smooth, and mostly it works as designed.

Then I encountered errors in log files:

```
 SSL_accept: 1408F10B: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

Not all clients trigger that, for some strange reason. Connecting from CentOS using links - error shows up (tried multiple machines). Connecting from Ubuntu using links - no error.

Tried using wget, and all is smooth with TLSv1, but error shows up with SSLv3. At the same time, wget reports:

```
OpenSSL: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Unable to establish SSL connection.

Here is my config:

```
pid = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pid
debug = 3
output = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.log

socket=l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket=r:TCP_NODELAY=1

verify=3    

; fixing "fingerprint does not match" error
fips=no

[https]
accept=12.34.56.78:443
connect=127.0.0.1:80
TIMEOUTclose=0
xforwardedfor=yes
CAfile = /path/to/ssl/example.com.cabundle
cert=/path/to/ssl/example.com.crt
key=/path/to/ssl/example.com.key
```

Anyone has any insight as to what's happening here? Googled for multiple hours now, can't figure it out.

OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008.

Stunnel version: 4.32

**EDIT:**

Here is an output of `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -ssl3`

```
CONNECTED(00000004)
3897:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1086:SSL alert number 40
3897:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:530:
```

Same with `-tls1` works OK, without any errors.

Comment: [SSLv3 Is Comprehensively Broken](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7568#page-3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, problem was solved... I added this to configuration:

```
sslVersion = all
options = NO_SSLv2
```

As far as I understand, error was related to SSLv23. Now all works as expected.

Comment: I also needed to add `fips = no`

Comment: You can also add `option = NO_SSLv3` to force one of the TLS variants to be selected.

Answer (score 6):

`SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number` is the key.  It seems that lynx on your CentOS systems isn't using SSLv3.

It'll be easier to check the exact behavior with `openssl s_client`:

Check what happens with just SSLv3:

```
openssl s_client -connect server:443 -ssl3
```

And with just TLS:

```
openssl s_client -connect server:443 -tls1
```

Comment: Edited the post to provide more details

Comment: Try adding `-no_ticket` to the SSLv3 attempt.  Looks like [this OpenSSL bug](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=1629).

Comment: Hmm, shows unknown option

Comment: @Serge That's.. strange.  What do you get from `openssl version`?

Answer (score 0):

I had to set

```
options = -NO_SSLv3
```

to deactivate the now **default** option of NO_SSLv3. (The server connecting to doesn't do TLS)