# Protecting against POODLE SSL on stunnel

Tags: ssl, openssl, stunnel

How can I mitigate POODLE SSL vulnerability when using stunnel as HTTPS reverse proxy?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can disable SSLv3 protocol on stunnel altogether.

From stunnel documentation:

> **sslVersion** = SSL_VERSION
>
> select version of SSL protocol Allowed
>
> options: all, SSLv2, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2

I've added this to the config file:

```
sslVersion = TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
```

And now I am not able to connect with SSLv3 (using `openssl s_client -connect my.domain.com:443 -ssl3`)

**NOTE**: Some older versions of stunnel and OpenSSL don't support TLSv1.2 (and even TLSv1.1). In this case, remove them from `sslVersion` directive to avoid `incorrect version of ssl protocol` error.

Comment: I get the following error when I use the sslVersion = from above:  Starting stunnel: file /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf line 6: Incorrect version of SSL protocol.  This is with 4.29.  Can anyone else confirm that they do not get this error?

Comment: Some older versions of stunnel do not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1. Try removing those, leaving just TLSv1. Confirmed this working on an older installation.

Answer (score 10):

if you prefer to stick with older stunnel (like the 4.53 in your Debian Stable), you can disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 with:

```
sslVersion = all
options = NO_SSLv2
options = NO_SSLv3
```

instead of

```
sslVersion = TLSv1
```

which would disable TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 also.

Comment: This works for me with stunnel 4.53 (Debian) and a modern OpenSSL (1.0.1e+security patches that Debian provides). I can connect to it using TLSv1.2. Yay!

Answer (score 2):

Since I cannot comment, I will "answer" (sorry).

Anyway, I am running stunnel 5.01 and I also get the "incorrect version of SSL" error after making the change to sslVersion:

```
[!] Server is down
[.] Reading configuration from file stunnel.conf
[!] Line 4: "sslVersion = TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2": Incorrect version of SSL protocol
```

Fixed (for me). Had to upgrade stunnel to v5.06 (most current release as of today). Conf file is exactly the same so I guess there is some mojo happening between v5.01 and v5.06 that goes beyond a mere mortal to understand.